# Designing a UIView in Xib

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, xib

Sorrry, Image looks so big. My question is very simple. Please see the below images

[image]

If I camera orientation is changed, it will be like this...

[image]

So if I have any controls below the button it will be hidden, So I guess I need scroll view here for landscape and make it hidden for Portrait, If it is the case, Do I need to add scroll view for all my views in my application.

thanks for your helps

Comment: Just anchor the button to the top instead of the bottom.

Comment: @msgambel not only buttons, some view may fit in portrait not for landscape, controls will hide because of its height, in that case we need to add scroll view right?. If that is the case every view for my application need scroll view. Just I want to know am I going in right direction

Comment: these images could be a lot more useful in this question: what goes in the big blank white space?  a picture from the camera roll or the actual camera input or?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I took screen shot from iPod touch, and synced with my system it looks very big :)